# OWL Carousel Banner Slider is not responsive

Tags: magento-2.1

I have installed OWL Carousel bannerslider extension successfully,but it is not been responsive after 768 pixel.

Comment: Which banner slider you have installed , pass the slider URL

Comment: Im using OWL Carousel bannerslider

Comment: you have to reduce no.of items in low resolutions

Comment: check your settings carefully... are you using this one https://www.weltpixel.com/owl-carousel-and-slider.html

Comment: I had given only one item to display in all breakpoints.Im using weltpixel.com/owl-carousel-and-slider.html

Comment: create a demo user and give the details to check the settings

Comment: I just created and tested , it works fine ...let me share some settings which can help you out

Comment: please clear cache

Comment: could not save some settings, may be permission issue...sharing screen shot , match the settings and clear cache

Comment: match the settings , i was not able to save some settings and couldn't edit general settings. give me permissions to edit them thanks

Comment: You can use `aheadworks` silder for `home , category and product` page banner. It is fully responsive slider.

Answer (score 2):

Try Matching your settings for custom slider, this can help all the users who are using this plugin for banner slider.

[image]

clear cache if enabled